Output of Tracker.Current.Contact from SC 8.2
Hi what is actual output for below code in Sc 8.2 (with mongo db collections)?
Contact contact = Tracker.Current.Contact

In Sitecore 8.2 with MongoDB collections, the code retrieves the current contact associated with the current tracking session.
Tracker.Current: This refers to the current tracking session in Sitecore. Sitecore's Tracker is used to track visitor interactions, such as page views, and associate them with a particular contact (a visitor on your site).
Tracker.Current.Contact: The Contact property refers to the contact associated with the current session. The contact is essentially a user who is tracked by Sitecore, which stores various details about their behavior, like page views, form submissions, or other interactions. The Contact object holds all the data related to this particular user session.
So this is the actual output -

If the user has already been tracked, and there is an active contact, Tracker.Current.Contact will return an object of type Contact, which contains all the information about the visitor (such as their ID, email, interaction history, etc.).

If no contact has been created for the session, Tracker.Current.Contact will return null. This might happen if it's the first time a user is visiting your site and they haven't been identified yet, or if the tracking session has expired.


